# Writing to a Binary file in C, interpreting output

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

I'm trying to test writing to a binary file in c, and just want to make sense of my output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void writeToFile();

int main(void) {

    writeToFile();

    return(0);
}

void writeToFile() {
    FILE * file = fopen("file.bin","w");
    char * string;

    if(file == NULL)
        printf("Problem with file\n");

    string = malloc(sizeof(char)*6);

    strcpy(string,"Hello");

    fwrite(&string,sizeof(string),strlen(string)+1,file);

    fclose(file);

}
```

I'm interpreting my results using the commands:

```
od -c file.bin
```

Which displays octal output.
And gives me this:

```
0000000   @ 022   # 001  \0  \0  \0  \0 020 020   # 001  \0  \0  \0  \0                                                                                         
0000020 300 016 374   ? 377 177  \0  \0 264 006   @  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0                                                                                         
0000040   @  \a   @  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0 200 365   c 274 020 177  \0  \0                                                                                         
0000060
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this output, I know it's in octal, but how do I know my string "Hello" was written correctly?

I was thinking I could convert the output to ascii using an ascii table, but I'm not sure if that's doable here? Is there a simple way I can check if string "Hello" was written correctly?

Maybe I could read the output back in, and somehow check if the string "Hello" exists within it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are passing the address of 'string' to fwrite. You should pass its value.

Comment: It might be easier to display the output in hex (I use `od -Ax -t x1`

Comment: You are writing the *pointer* `string` (not the thing it points to, which is the string), and a bunch of garbage that happens to be after it.

Comment: You are supposed to open your file with mode `wb` instead of `w` if you wish to have complete control of what is read and written. Using `fopen()` with `w` only is not suitable for binary mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
 fwrite(&string,sizeof(string),strlen(string)+1,file);
```

should be

```
 fwrite(string, strlen(string)+1, 1, file);
```

Because

1. You already have a pointer to the item - do not need the pointer to that pointer - hence `string` and not `&string`
2. The size of the item is `strlen(string) +`
3. You have one item

This is why you are getting output that does not make sense as it is random stuff in memory.

**EDIT**

ALso

```
if(file == NULL)
    printf("Problem with file\n");
```

should be

```
if(file == NULL) {
    printf("Problem with file\n");
    return;
 }
```

as there is little that can be done with a null `file` in the rest of the function

Comment: Oh okay, and if i were to have a struct that has a char *, I would write it the same way? Also what does the first column of numbers represent?

Comment: If you have a `struct`  you would need to serialise it in some way (google serialisation). Why not read the manual page for `fwrite` to find out about the numbers

Comment: Care to link a page about serialization for structs in regards to C? Googling it myself seems to yield minimal results.

Comment: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=serialization+struct+C+example seems to have a few good starting points

Answer (score 1):

To write to file in binary you should use the "wb" option, for write byte.

```
FILE * file = fopen("file.bin","wb");
```

As for knowing if the file is written correctly, the bulletproof way, (allthough probably it exits a better one) is simply to read the file back in with "rb" and print it in normal format.